# Lock in multithreaded App C#

Tags: c#, multithreading, thread-safety, locking

Lets say I have declared a class like this :

```
public class PersistableObject<TObject> where TObject : class, new()
{
    private readonly object objectLocker = new object();
    private TObject persistableObject;

    public TObject Object
    {
        get
        {
            lock (this.objectLocker)
            {
                return this.persistableObject; 
            }
        }

        set
        {
            lock (this.objectLocker)
            {
                this.persistableObject = value;
            }
        }
    }

    public bool Persist()
    {
        lock (this.objectLocker)
        {
            // Do Persist Object in file
        }
    }

    public bool Retrieve()
    {
        lock (this.objectLocker)
        {
            // Do Retrieve Object from file
        }
    }
}
```

This class is responsible for storing a variable of any type, persist it to a file and retrieve it from a file.

As you can see, I used the same lock (an object) to lock 4 operations :

1. Getting the actual object
2. Setting the actual object
3. Persisting the object to file
4. Retrieving the object from file

Is this the correct approach from **concurrency** point of view? Am I completely in the safe zone, considering that this class is used by different threads?

**UPDATE :**

The most important thing for me here, is only one thread should have access to the object at any given time (no matter it wants to get, set, retrieve or persist it). Considering this in mind, is it the correct approach? will any deadlocks or other nasty things happen?

Comment: That depends on how you plan to use it, and what the callers of the application *expect* it to do.  When one thread goes and sets a value and then persists it right afterwards is it okay for another thread to set a different value in between those two method calls?

Comment: You're likely intending to make `persist` and `retrieve` atomic operations, which this fails to do entirely.

Comment: @Servy No, it is not okay, but the thing is practically no one will be setting the object directly. Threads use the object (which is a list) to add or remove objects and I'm ok with it, because any changes should be saved

Comment: @PrestonGuillot So, what do you recommend to make them atomic?

Comment: @Arashv If it's not okay, and it can happen, then you have your answer.  If it *is* okay, or you know it will never happen, then that particular case isn't an issue.  If you know you'll never depend on multiple calls to one of these objects to be executed "together", then you're likely fine.

Comment: @Servy Let me put it in another way. What I'm trying to do here is to make sure, when one thread is accessing the "Object" member, the other ones are not able to persist, retrieve or change it. Now, is this code able to do that? Can any deadlock situations or other bad things happen?

Comment: "when one thread is accessing the "Object" member, the other ones are not able to persist or retrieve it" Yes, this does that. "Can any deadlock situations [...] happen" No.  "Can any [...] other bad things happen"  Most certainly yes, quite a number of other bad things can happen, depending on how the type is used, and how you expect it to work.

Comment: @Servy Thank you so much, your comments were very useful. Can you please post a full answer so I will be able to mark it as accepted? One other thing, can you please tell me what are the other bad things that can happen?

Comment: There are *lots* of other bad things that can happen, way too many to try to cover them all.  Books are written on the subject.  I described one, and those are *exactly* the kinds of things that you should be worrying about with a type such as this, not just blatantly ignoring.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thread-safety is a property of the whole system, not of a single class or method. Individual operations on an instance of this class will execute exclusively, but maybe you require multiple operations to be atomic. The class has no way to do that.

So is it thread-safe or not? Only you can tell because only you know how the class is being used. If operations on this class are truly independent, then it is safe.

If all you had do to obtain thread-safety way to just lock every member of any class, then threading would be a simple task. Threading is complex because it touches everything in a cross-cutting manner.

Comment: No I don't expect to make a class "Thread-Safe", just by putting a lock around each member of it.

Comment: Let me put it in another way. What I'm trying to do is to make sure, when one thread is accessing the "Object" member, the other one is not able to persist or retrieve the object. Now, is this code able to do that? Can any deadlock situations occur?

Comment: Another thing I may add is I'm not trying to make the persist or retrieve operations atomic, I want to make sure no one will change, persist or retrieve "Object", at the same time that another thread is changing, persisting or retrieving "Object". It's more of a concurrency problem than just thread-safety. Sorry for not mentioning that in the question

Comment: After the getter has executed, the lock is released. A Retrieve or Persist can not happen. I understand you don't want that. Solution: increase the scope of the lock. Hold the lock not only while executing the getter, but also while working with the TObject instance that was returned. You could expose the lock object to the caller.

Comment: Just to drive home the point: make all code that works on the data hold the lock. At the moment you're accessing the data while not under the lock. That's the problem.

Comment: Your answer was not exactly what I wanted but gave me the idea to fix it. In addition I really wanted to give some credit to @Servy for his patience in answering me, but unfortunately he didn't post the answer, so I'll mark yours as accepted

Answer (score 0):

Define "being in the safe zone".

Imagine a piece of code executing on multiple threads using your class to

1. read an object from a file
2. modify that object
3. write that object back to the file

None of the locking you do here will help making that scenario thread-safe.